# move_uploaded_file error php won't upload to filepath

Tags: php, file, file-upload

I'm writing a script to upload user input and images to a place in my file system (currently on a different server).
I get an error
 move_uploaded_file(images//test.pdf): failed to open stream: Permission denied in   ..

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_USERNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

 $title = $_POST["title"];
 $authors = $_POST["authors"];
 $description = $_POST["description"];
 $price = $_POST["price"];

$uploads_dir = "images/";

        $tmp_name = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
        $name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
        $tmp_name2 = $_FILES["content"]["tmp_name"];
        $name2 = $_FILES["content"]["name"];



     move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
     move_uploaded_file($tmp_name2, "$uploads_dir/$name2");

    $file_path=$uploads_dir. basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $file_path2=$uploads_dir. basename( $_FILES["content"]["name"]);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO books (title,authors,description,price,image, content)
 VALUES ('$title', '$authors', '$description', '$price',$file_path', '$file_path2')") ; 
 $stmt->execute();
```

I've looked at similar questions on here but the answers haven't concluded my problem. I have tried the $uploads_dir variable as images/ and as its complete path /project/folder/user/images/ both give the same error.

Note: this php script is in the parent folder of images/.

Comment: use move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $uploads_dir $name);

Comment: give permission to images folder

Comment: I'm receiving a syntax error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$name'

Comment: I've given permissions on the image folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a File Permission error. You can check whether a directory is writable or not by,

```
$directoryName = "specify your directory name here"; 
if(is_writable($directoryName){ 
    echo "Directory is writable"; // Returns TRUE if it's writable.
} 
else{ 

}
```

More on [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php).

Comment: Ah ok, interesting, thank you for this.. it appears that the directory is not writable, perhaps I'm writing the chmod command incorrectly?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is clearly related to permissions. The user under which the php is running doesn't have permissions to write in this images folder. Change the owner of the folder or change the permissions.

Comment: I used the command  chmod 755 on the folder, that didn't change anything.

Comment: 755 may not help you because the system user still cannot write to the directory. Try 777, but keep in mind that this is not secure. The better approach is to change the owner of the folder to the system user which runs the Apache server / PHP-FPM

Comment: Oh man, I was thinking that would work 777 didn't change the error, Do you know how I change owner? I just tried chown -R user images/

Comment: If 777 permission doesn't work the problem is somewhere else. Check where the folder `images` is located relative to the script. They must be in same folder.

Comment: ok, so the script was in my public folder(which is a directory above images).  I've now changed the target directory and ran chmod 777 in this folder, but still no luck.